# Area between circular curves

Tags: matlab, geometry, drawing, area, curve

I'm trying to calculate the surface between two circular curves (yellow surface [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1tI7.jpg) as simplification) but I'm somehow stuck since I don't have datapoints at the same angular values of the two curves. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Picture:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1tI7.jpg]

Comment: How did you select the yellow surface?

Comment: I colored it with Gimp since I didn't know how to do it in matlab... XD

Comment: How accurate do you need to be?

Comment: I try to implement a fitting algorithm between these two curves, which evaluates the error based on this surface.
I can't use just a basic icp fitting since thiese 2D-lines are derived from 3D curves and no linear shifting is allowed in 2D...

Comment: What I'd do is create 2 separate 2D maks (logical matrices) with values 1 if inside circle and 0 if outside. Then compute the XOR of those maks, and count the ones. Finally, knowing how much area you defined to be a pixel in the mask, convert number of pixels to area. The more accuracy required, the more memory you'd need

Comment: ok, I do understand your approach. But how could I generate those masks?

Comment: Depend on what you use to generate those plots

Comment: just the general plot() command

Comment: Sorry: depends what you use to generate the data on those plots

Comment: it's 288 equally spaced points along each line.
this is also why the datapoints do not have the same angular values....

Comment: I dont think you used 288 to generate the data. You used that to generate the plot.

Comment: the datapoints come from a different project I don't have access to... I just have the equally spaced datapoints for the plot :-/

Comment: You can then use `inpolygon` to test if your mask points are in that shape I believe

Comment: I could achieve what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help!! =)

Comment: Please do post the code you used here (as an answer) so future people can also get help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function area = area_between_curves(initial,corrected)

   interval = 0.1;
   x = -80:interval:80;
   y = -80:interval:80;
   [X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

   in_initial = inpolygon(X,Y,initial(:,1),initial(:,2));
   in_corrected = inpolygon(X,Y,corrected(:,1),corrected(:,2));
   in_area = xor(in_initial,in_corrected);

   area = interval^2*nnz(in_area);

   % visualization
   figure
   hold on
   plot(X(in_area),Y(in_area),'r.')
   plot(X(~in_area),Y(~in_area),'b.')

end
```

If I use the lines of the question, this is the result:

[image: figure]

```
area = 1.989710000000001e+03
```

Comment: I realized that numel() is actually wrong here and changed it to nnz() instead.

Comment: As it is logical, you can also just do `sum`

Comment: yeah, but nnz is faster...
    a=[0,0,1;0,1,1;1,1,0];

     tic;sum(a(:));toc
     Elapsed time is 0.001195 seconds.

     tic;nnz(a);toc
     Elapsed time is 0.000149 seconds.

Comment: I did not know that!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have the x,y coordinates which you used to the plot. I obtained them here using `imfreehand`. I used `inpolygon` to generate a binary mask for each curve and then apply `xor` on them to get a mask of the desired area:

```
% x,y were obtained using imfreehand on 100x100 image and getPosition()
x = [21;22;22;22;22;22;22;23;23;23;23;23;23;24;25;25;26;26;27;28;29;30;30;31;32;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;79;80;80;81;81;81;82;82;82;82;83;83;83;84;84;85;85;86;86;86;86;86;86;85;84;84;83;82;81;80;79;78;77;76;75;74;73;72;71;70;69;68;67;66;65;64;63;62;61;60;59;58;57;56;55;54;53;52;51;50;49;48;47;46;45;44;43;42;41;40;39;38;37;36;35;34;33;32;31;30;29;28;27;26;25;25;24;24;23;22;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21;21];
y = [44;43;42;41;40;39;38;37;36;35;34;33;32;31;30;29;28;27;26;25;24;23;22;21;20;19;18;18;17;17;17;17;17;16;16;16;16;16;16;15;15;14;14;14;14;14;14;15;15;15;16;16;17;17;17;17;18;18;18;19;20;20;21;22;23;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;56;57;57;58;59;59;60;61;61;61;61;61;60;60;60;59;58;57;56;56;55;55;54;54;54;54;54;54;54;54;54;55;55;55;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;61;62;63;63;64;64;65;65;66;66;66;66;66;66;65;64;63;62;61;60;59;58;57;56;55;54;53;52;51;50;49;48;47;46;45;44];
% generate arbitrary xy
x1 = (x - 50)./10; y1 = (y - 50)./10;
x2 = (x - 50)./10; y2 = (y - 40)./10;
% generate binary masks using poly2mask
pixelSize = 0.01; % resolution
xx = min([x1(:);x2(:)]):pixelSize:max([x1(:);x2(:)]);
yy = min([y1(:);y2(:)]):pixelSize:max([y1(:);y2(:)]);
[xg,yg] = meshgrid(xx,yy);
mask1 = inpolygon(xg,yg,x1,y1);
mask2 = inpolygon(xg,yg,x2,y2);
% add both masks (now their common area pixels equal 2)
combinedMask = mask1 + mask2;
% XOR on both of them
xorMask = xor(mask1,mask2);
% compute mask area in units (rather than pixels)
Area = bwarea(xorMask)*pixelSize^2;
% plot
subplot(131);
plot(x1,y1,x2,y2,'LineWidth',2);
title('Curves');
axis square
set(gca,'YDir','reverse');
subplot(132);
imshow(combinedMask,[]);
title('Combined Mask');
subplot(133);
imshow(xorMask,[]);
title(['XNOR Mask, Area = ' num2str(Area)]);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes and no. This computes the are in pixels, not in real area (i.e. whatever the axis are saying). To generalize, add `x=x/3;y=y/6` to your code before `x1=...` and modify the `Area` calculation

Comment: Thank you @Ander! didn't noticed that. I've change my answer to use `inpolygon` instead of `poly2mask` which deals with that